# Spring MVC dispatcher-servlet returns a 404 Error and not Welcome page

Tags: spring, servlets, model-view-controller, dispatcher

I have searched all the answers to 404 error pages about Spring MVC dispatcher, and I cannot find the answer to my issue.

I am also having an issue with Spring framework 4.1.6 as it no longer has the SimpleForm for forms for log in.

I understand that I need Maven to use the lastest Spring Security log in, which I plan to create a new Spring/Maven project and import this application into.

Just really want to know I have flow control going on before I export it to the Spring/Maven project. So any help with why my Welcome screen is not being found ....is much appreciated.

Heres my web.xml

```
enter code here<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMVCpizza</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/springMVCpizza-servletConfig.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMVCpizza</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Here is my dispatcher-servlet:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pizza.controllers" />


    <bean id="urlMapping"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="Welcome.jsp">welcomePageController</prop>
    </props>
</property>
    </bean>

    <bean id= "welcomePageController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="LogIn" ref="LoginFormController">
       </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginFormController" class="com.pizza.controllers.loginFormController"></bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang"/></bean>

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="interceptors">
<list>
 <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/> 
</list>
</property>
<property name="urlMap">
<map>
<entry key="/LogIn.jsp">
<ref bean="loginFormController"/>
</entry>
</map>
</property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="loginFormController" class="com.pizza.web.LoginFormController">

    `enter code here`<property name="commandName"><value>login</value></property>
  `enter code here`  <property name="commandClass"><value>com.pizza.web.LogIn</value></property>


     </bean>
    <bean id="loginValidator" class="com.pizza.web.LoginValidator"/>
    <bean id="loginFormController" class="com.pizza.controllers.LoginFormController">
    <property name="sessionForm"><value>false</value></property>
    <property name="commandName"><value>login</value></property>
    <property name="commandClass"><value>com.pizza.web.LogIn</value>      </property>
    <property name="validator"><ref bean="loginValidator"/></property>
    <property name="formView"><value>LogIn.jsp</value></property>
    <property name="successView"><value>success</value></property>
    <property name="urlMap">
    <map>
    <entry key="/LogIn.jsp">
    <ref bean="loginFormController"/>
    </entry>
    </map>
    </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="LocaleChangeInterceptor" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="hl"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>

    <bean id="ViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >

     <!-- maximum file size in bytes -->
     <property name ="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>

      </bean>
```

Heres the Welcome jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome to the Pizza Store</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
    <center>
    <h1>Welcome to the Pizza Store!</h1>
     <a href="LogIn.jsp">Sign In</a>
    <p>Or </p> <a href="createAccount.jsp">Create Account</a>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```